# Using postfix/prefix increment operators in compound literals in C99

Tags: c99, postfix-operator, compound-literals, prefix-operator

There is an example borrowed from CARM (C A Reference Manual, Samuel P. Harbison III, Guy L. Steele Jr., 2002, Prentice Hall), page 218-219.
I write all of three code-chunk in one source:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(){
    int *p[5];
    int i=0;
    m:
    p[i]=(int [1]){i};
    if(++i<5)goto m;
    printf("f1: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void f2(){
    int *p[5];
    int i=0;
    p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
    p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
    p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
    p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
    p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
    printf("f2: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void f3(){
    int *p[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        p[i]=(int [1]){i};
    }
    printf("f3: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(){ f1(); f2(); f3(); }
```

f2 function doesn't work properly:

```
user@debian:~/test7$ gcc -std=c11 ./carm_1.c -o carm_1
user@debian:~/test7$ ./carm_1
f1: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4 
f2: p[0]=-2106668384 p[1]=-2106668408 p[2]=32765 p[3]=2 p[4]=3 
f3: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4
```

But when i rewrote it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(){
    int *p[5];
    int i=0;
    m:
    p[i]=(int [1]){i};
    if(++i<5)goto m;
    printf("f1: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void f2(){
    int *p[5];
    int i=-1;
    p[i]=(int [1]){++i};
    p[i]=(int [1]){++i};
    p[i]=(int [1]){++i};
    p[i]=(int [1]){++i};
    p[i]=(int [1]){++i};
    printf("f2: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void f3(){
    int *p[5];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        p[i]=(int [1]){i};
    }
    printf("f3: ");
    for(i=0;i<5;++i)
        printf("p[%d]=%d ",i,*(p[i]));
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main(){ f1(); f2(); f3(); }
```

f2 function works fine:

```
user@debian:~/test7$ gcc -std=c11 ./carm_2.c -o carm_2
user@debian:~/test7$ ./carm_2
f1: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4 
f2: p[0]=0 p[1]=1 p[2]=2 p[3]=3 p[4]=4 
f3: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4
```

Why ? These two variants of f2 function differs in value returned by postfix/infix increment of i (in compound literal). In the first  case it is temporary value. The result of postfix increment operator is not lvalue. And the result of prefix increment operator is also not lvalue (in according to page 226 of CARM). Please, help me to understand. (sorry for my english).

Comment: My question is whether there is a sequence point after the initializer of the compound literal.  If not, then both versions of `f2` are undefined behavior.  If there is, then the bug in the original `f2` is that the post-increment occurs before `p[i]` is evaluated and the original `f2` is doing `p[1] = (int [1]){0}; ... p[5] = (int [1]){4};` which is obviously UB since `p[0]` is never initialized and `p[5]` is out of bounds.  But your version would fix that bug and correctly do `p[0] = (int [1]){0}; ... p[4] = (int [1]){4};`.

Comment: There's a line in the standard that an initializer which is *not* part of a compound literal is a full expression, and therefore has a sequence point, but that does not apply here since our initializer *is* part of a compound literal.  Still, I can't quite tell if there is some other condition that would create a sequence point in this case.  But either way, I don't think it has anything to do with lvalue/rvalue issues.

Comment: clang gives warnings about "unsequenced modification and access" so maybe it is right and there is no sequence point.  (gcc gives no warning, however, though it does on some simpler sequence point errors, e.g. `p[i] = i++;`).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, clang gives warnings:  `user@debian:~/test7$ clang -std=c11 ./carm_1.c -o carm_11
./carm_1.c:19:18: warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Wunsequenced]
        p[i]=(int [1]){i++};
          ~             ^
... 5 warnings generated.`  And the code does not work: 
`user@debian:~/test7$ ./carm_11
f1: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4 
f2: p[0]=0 p[1]=0 p[2]=1 p[3]=2 p[4]=3 
f3: p[0]=4 p[1]=4 p[2]=4 p[3]=4 p[4]=4`

Comment: Well sure - undefined behavior is *undefined* and can do anything, including what you want.  It's possible that the compiler happens to do the increment of `i` before the other access to it, and that the uninitialized `p[0]` happens to contain a pointer to `0`, and that the write to `p[5]` doesn't cause a crash.  If all those things happen then the code will behave as you see.

Comment: It's not too improbable that the uninitialized `p[0]` points to `0`; because of the previous use of the stack it is likely to point to the first compound literal that you create, which is the one that you initialize to `0` (and whose address also goes in `p[1]`).

Comment: Just curious - what do Harbison and Steele say about their `f2` example?

Comment: @Nate Eldredge. About `f2` Harbison wrote: "The following code fills `p` with pointers to different arrays, and `*(p[i])==i`". Thats all.

Comment: Come to think of it, even if there were a sequence point, the order of evaluation of `p[i]` and `++i` is still unspecified.  So in your version of `f2`, when `i == -1` your `p[i] = (int [1]){++i}` could do still do `p[-1] = (int [1]){0};` which would be bad.

Comment: So I guess the short answer is just that H&S have a bug in their code.  If they wrote it as `p[i] = (int [1]){i}; i++; p[i] = (int [1]){i}; i++; ...` it would be fine and it would behave as they state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue about lvalues and temporaries; but rather an unrelated bug in H&S's example.

In the statement `p[i]=(int [1]){i++};`, there is a tricky question as to whether there is a sequence point after the `i++`, which seems to hinge on whether `i++` is a *full expression*.  In C17 it is explicitly stated that an initializer *that is not part of a compound literal* is a full expression, which would seem to imply that the `i++` is not a full expression and that there is no sequence point.  In that case, the statement in question would be undefined behavior, as would the `p[i]=(int [1]){++i};` in your version.

However, C99 doesn't seem to have had the "not part of a compound literal" exception, so I'm not quite sure what the situation was there.  But even if there is a sequence point after the side effect of `i++`, still as far as I know, the order of evaluation of the left and right sides of `=` is unspecified.  So if the compiler chooses to evaluate the right side first (including its side effects), the statement becomes `p[1] = (int [1]){0};` and leaves `p[0]` uninitialized, causing undefined behavior when it is dereferenced.  By the same token, the last statement becomes `p[5] = (int [1]){4}` which is also UB since `p` is of length 5.

For a compiler that consistently chooses that ordering, your code would work; but for a compiler that chose the other order, your code could become `p[-1] = (int [1]){0}` which is likewise UB.  So I don't think your version is strictly correct either.

H&S probably should not have tried to be so clever, and just written

```
int i=0;
p[i] = (int [1]){i};
i++;
p[i] = (int [1]){i};
i++;
p[i] = (int [1]){i};
i++;
p[i] = (int [1]){i};
i++;
p[i] = (int [1]){i};
i++;
```

Then the code would be correct and would do what they say: `p[0], ..., p[4]` contain five different pointers, all pointing to `int`s whose lifetimes continue through the `printf` loop, and such that `*(p[0]) == 0`, `*(p[1]) == 1`, etc.